# This CSS works when col 2 is marked up before col 1 but not vice versa: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

What am I doing wrong here? I want two columns, the left one (col 1) fluid, the right (col 2) with a fixed width of 300px. My code works fine, so long as I mark up col 2 before col 1 in the HTML. (The order of the id definitions in the CSS doesn't matter.) For readability of the markup I would like to mark up col 1 before col 2, but when I do I get a page in which the right-hand column, col 2, is missing.

***CSS***

```
#col1 {
        width:auto;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-right:300px;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
#col2 {
        float:right;
        padding:10px;
        width: 300px;
      }
```

***HTML***

This works:

```
<div id="col2">
    <p>Hello 2</p>
</div>
<div id="col1">
    <p>Hello 1</p>
</div>
```

This doesn't:

```
<div id="col1">
    <p>Hello 1</p>
</div>
<div id="col2">
    <p>Hello 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So, the trick is with `float:right`. If you don't need to support old browsers, you might look into [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) or [column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts).

Answer (score 1):

When you float an element right, you are saying that everything after it in the DOM will flow to the left of it. There are other available options for you. For example, you can display:inline-block for both DIVs and set vertical-align:top. You could also use display:table-cell.

Answer (score 0):

The `float: right` is causing the issue.  It is taken out of the flow of the document and moved to the right.  Then the rest of the elements are rendered.  Since a `div` is a block element, the browser clears the line and displays the next div under it.

When you have them reversed, the div is floated to the right and the other column is placed in the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

You're margin on the right of div 1 is screwing it up. You want to float div 1 on the left and div 2 to the right and get rid of your margins.

```css
*, html, body{box-sizing: border-box;}
body, html{margin: 0;}
#col1 {
    float: left;
    width:calc(100% - 300px);
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#col2 {
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="col1">
    <p>Hello 1</p>
</div>
<div id="col2">
    <p>Hello 2</p>
</div>
```

Another way to do this is to use a container div with relative positioning and then place your divs inside of it with absolute positioning.